# How can you use "use framework" Foundation " and " use scripting additions " with " info for POSIX file "?

Tags: frameworks, applescript, foundation

I went around every framework, every time I try "info for POSIX file" or "info for file" I have a file error not found. 
For the moment, I've gone back to the "do shell script" (basename, dirname, ls) which works very well. it is  very penible in an applescript script to have recourse to "do shell script"

below an example script that does not work with "use framework" Foundation "
and " info for POSIX file "

```
global testdir
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

    set testdir to POSIX path of (choose file)

    set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to info for POSIX file testdir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info for` takes an alias or file reference, such as the result from `choose file`.  `POSIX file` is from the **StandardAdditions** Scripting Addition (**Foundation** is a Cocoa framework that applies more to AppleScriptObjC), and is just one of those items that doesn’t work well everywhere.  In this case, it works better as a coercion:

```
set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to info for (testdir as POSIX file)
```

`info for` has also been deprecated for a while - **System Events** is the recommend alternative, and tends to work better with POSIX paths:

```
tell application "System Events" to set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to disk item testdir
```

Comment: Thank you both, both solutions work.
Applescript is a discovery every day, things that work and sometimes you have to change the presentation of the subject to make it work.
Thanks again to Vadian and red_menace, for giving us information and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the POSIX path *detour*:

```
set testfile to (choose file) -- The name testdir for a file is confusing 
set {name:Nm, name extension:Ex} to info for testfile
```

Comment: Thank you both, both solutions work.
Applescript is a discovery every day, things that work and sometimes you have to change the presentation of the subject to make it work.
Thanks again to Vadian and red_menace, for giving us information and solutions.